# IndexedDB não conecta em Android 4.2

Tags: banco-de-dados, apache-cordova, intel-xdk, indexeddb

Estou trabalhando na IDE IntelXDK, e utilizo o IndexedDB para persistir alguns arquivos. Ao emular o projeto na IDE, tudo funciona perfeito, ele faz a conexão, ele traz todos os dados, tudo funciona. Quando gero meu APK, e instalo em um smartphone rodando com android 4.2, ele faz a parte de ir no servidor e verificar os dados porem quando preciso ir no banco interno do aplicativo ele não consegue acessar.

Identifiquei que ele não está nem entrando na área da inicialização do banco de dados. Verifico o log e nada de erro acontece.

Qual a forma para verificar este problema, inicialmente pensei que fosse espaço no celular, porem testei em outro e não funcionou também.

O inicio de meu código é o seguinte.

```
    //provide database name and version number
var request = indexedDB.open("DB_MINHACELULA", 1);
var db = null;

function DeletaBanco(){    
    var bdDeleta = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("DB_MINHACELULA");
    bdDeleta.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("Error " + event.target.errorCode);
    };
    bdDeleta.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log("Deletado com sucesso!");
    };
}


request.onupgradeneeded = function(){
    db = request.result;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                  TABELA USUARIO LOGADO                  //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var logado= db.createObjectStore("tbl_USUAR_LOGAD", {keyPath: "COD_IDENT_USUAR"});

    logado.createIndex("COD_IDENT_USUAR", "COD_IDENT_USUAR", {unique: true});
    logado.createIndex("TXT_EMAIL_USUAR", "TXT_EMAIL_USUAR", {unique: false});
    logado.createIndex("TXT_SENHA_USUAR", "TXT_SENHA_USUAR", {unique: false});
```

> Como não da nenhum erro, não consigo trazer nenhuma informação mais especifica, pois também não consigo debugar o código, teria como alguém me ajudar em algo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedDB não é suportado por todos os browsers, e segundo o site [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb) o browser nativo do Android suporta ele apenas a partir da versão 4.4

Segundo o mesmo site ele suporta o WebSQL, então uma alternativa pode ser usar o WebSQL ou então usar um polyfill como por exemplo o [IndexedDBShim](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim), que permite usar a API do IndexedDB em browsers com suporte apenas a WebSQL

Comment: Porem não é este o problema, pois testei em um 5.1 e também não funcionou.